# How to expand a FilteredTree after the filteration?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I have used a filtered tree in order to filter the contents.
If filter text is having some text, in this case tree is expanding properly.
But If the filter text is empty, then tree is not expanding at all.

Can some one guide me how to expand the filter tree if I the filter text becomes empty?

Also, In the beginning when Tree is having lot of data and I am  expanding it by `treeViewer.expandAll()` then it takes lot of time to open the dialog.
So, how to handle that performance?

Code Sample

```
FilteredTree filterTree = new FilteredTree(parent, SWT.VIRTUAL | SWT.BORDER, new PatternFilter());
filterTree.setQuickSelectionMode(true);
treeViewer = filterTree.getViewer();
treeViewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
treeViewer.setInput(input);
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
treeViewer.expandAll();
```

Comment: Are you asking about one of the two `FilteredTree` classes in Eclipse, or a normal `TreeViewer` with a filter? I think you need to show us a [mre]. If you have a lot of data in the tree you may need to use a virtual tree with `ILazyTreeContentProvider`

Comment: I am using org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree

Comment: You are specifying SWT.VIRTUAL - does the content provider implement ILazyTreeContentProvider? (SWT.VIRTUAL doesn't really do much without it). But if I remember correctly a lazy tree doesn't work properly with filters and the content provider has to do the filtering.

Comment: No, the content provider is implementing ITreeContentProvider as I was not understand how to filter items with content provider.
My filter needs to work same like FilteredTree and org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PatternFilter , so I used those.